# how to run javascript timer on different div with the same class name

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel, timer

---

I have search on stackover-flow about my question, but could not get a suiting answer. I have boxes generated by a loop from my back end code. this boxes a to be destroy after a countdown on the individual boxes. The time frame is supplied along side with the content of the boxes form the back end. Now depending on result from my back end code the boxes can be 10 or a million as the case may be. So i ran a jquery countdown timer on each of them in the loop. the problem there is that the countdown of the first box is used on all the rest boxes, so when the timer of the first comes to an end the destruction commands affect all the boxes.

below is an example of what am doing using laravel blade syntax.

```
    @forelse($boxe_deatails as $box_detail) 

    <div class="box-v2-detail-o">
    <div class="col-md-16 col-xs-6 pull-right" style="background: rgba(110, 151, 170, 0.57);min-width: 100%;min-height: 73px;float: right;padding: 10px;font-size: small;line-height: 2em;margin: 5px;">
    Timer to Run
   <div id="timer">
    @include('partials/count-timer')
    </div>
    </div>
    <img style="width: 60px;height: 60px;border: 3px solid #fff;" src="{{asset('asset/img/avatar.jpg')}}" class="img-responsive"/>
    <h4>Name {{$box_detail->name}} </h4>
    <big>Size {{ $box_detail->size}} </big>
    </div> 
 @empty
hello Empty
@endforelse
```

Now that is the loop. those data where gotten from my database.

count-timer file am using  [jquery.countdown-2.2.0](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/)
so all i have to do is select the targeted dom element and run the timer animation on it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').find("div#timer").countdown('{{$box_detail->created_at->addHours(13)}}', {elapse:true}).on('update.countdown', function(event) {
    $(this).text(event.strftime('%H Hr(s) : %M Min(s) : %S Sec(s)'));
    if (event.elapsed) {
       $.ajax({
        url     : '{{url('/timer-delete-box/'.$box_detail->id)}}',
        method  : 'get',
        success : function(response)
        { 
            alertify.notify('You did not make your payment before time. So your account has been pause', 'error', 9)

        } 
      })
    }
  });
</script>
```

so now the problem again is that the count down for the first box is use on all the boxes even when there timer are different i want the timer to run on each boxes. again the timer function for the first one is repeated on all the boxes whereas the time from the loop are different. When you view it you see a uniform time which is very wrong. Please someone should help me fix it .

Now i know the problem is that the function is running just once so how do call it multiple times base on the loop count.

Comment: maintain a global timer and use `:eq(1)` selector to `remove()` the box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if Implement the answer to your question it should look as this.

$('div#timer').each(function() {

```
        var $this = $(this), 

            finalDate = '{{$box_detail->created_at->addHours(13)}}';

          $this.countdown(finalDate,  {elapse:true}).on('update.countdown', function(event) {

          $this.text(event.strftime('%H Hr(s) : %M Min(s) : %S Sec(s)'));
          if (event.elapsed) {
           $.ajax({
            url     : '{{url('/time-pause-account/'.$Topay->id)}}',
            method  : 'get',
            success : function(response)
            { 
                alertify.notify('You did not make your payment before time. So your account has been pause', 'error', 9,  function(){
                    $('body').css({
                      'opacity' : '0',
                      'transition' : 'all 1s'
                    })
                $('body').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
                window.location = 'home'
              })
          })

            } 
          })
        }
         });
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to the problem what i have to do is use the each j-query loop for the boxes. which i did initially before asking this question however i was concatenating the countdown to the each function until i saw the documentation of the countdown timer for multiple instance. they still use the each loop but however did not concatenate the countdown obj to it.  [Link to the answer of my question](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/examples/multiple-instances.html)